# Regular expression to find a match for repeated pattern with wildcard

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a reg expression to find match of 11 different no/character repeated 3-5 times in a string of length 5.

eg: string-"1112a". Here 111 is repeated three times consecutively so this will return true.

- no/char are from 1-9,a,b.
- Wildcard: char b  is a wildcard means if b comes with any char/no  it will act like that no.

eg: string-"11b2a"; so here b will act like no 1.That means we have 3 1's .This will return true.

More examples:

- "22299" should return true.
- "222" makes a repeatition 3 times consecutively.
- repetation can be upto max 5. like "22222".

"22300"  should return false.
"22a13"  should return false.
"44b44"  should return true. Here b is wildcard act like 4.

Anybody please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `b4422` or `4b422` ?

Comment: @user3163916 so far i have been trying this /([(123456789a|b)])\1{2,4}/

Comment: @falsetru b4422 will return true.b will act as 4. 
4b422 return true. b act as 4.

Comment: What about `12131` or `b123b` or `b1a1b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capturing group `([0-9ab])` and backreference `\1` (this  match whatever matched by earlier group 1).

Javascript example:

```js
/([0-9ab])(\1|b){2,4}/.test('1112a')  // true
/([0-9ab])(\1|b){2,4}/.test('11b2a')  // true
/([0-9ab])(\1|b){2,4}/.test('22299')  // true
/([0-9ab])(\1|b){2,4}/.test('22300')  // false
/([0-9ab])(\1|b){2,4}/.test('22a13')  // false
/([0-9ab])(\1|b){2,4}/.test('44b44')  // true
```

Comment: Woww!!! i think we are close to result.
But wildcard before char/no is not returning true.
e.g: "b1188" should return true. But getting false.

Comment: @user3304794, Try `/([0-9ab])(\1|b){2,4}|b([0-9ab])(\3|b){1,3}|bb([0-9ab])(\3|b){0,2}/`

Comment: Greatt...Its working...Thanks a lot for helping me out with this problem :-)

One more thing can you help me out if i want a regular exp with above conditions and largest possible match with wildcard.
eg: 1bb33 Now it should match bb33 not 1bb.

2nd condition: It should match with largest no.
e.g: 11b22 it should match b22 not 11b beacuse 2>1.I think this is the only possible example for this condition.

Comment: @user3304794, I don't have idea. How about post a separated question?